# opencv cout access violation issue

Tags: opencv, access-violation, cout

I just installed opencv. I use VisualStudio 2013 the free version.
Whenever I use cout to display Mat object I get this:
Unhandled exception at 0x734ADE19 (msvcp100.dll) in myOpenCVStudy.exe: 0xC0000005: Access violation reading location 0x00000000.
My code is simply:

```
Mat M;
M.create(4, 4, CV_8UC(2));
cout << "M = " << endl << " " << M << endl << endl;
```

Any ideas?
Thanks

Comment: What is the error again?

Comment: Unhandled exception at 0x734ADE19 (msvcp100.dll) in myOpenCVStudy.exe: 0xC0000005: Access violation reading location 0x00000000

Comment: Ok, it seems like everything is wrong. All the operations I checked fail. Trying to do:

Comment: countNonZero, for example, gives an exception (Unhandled exception at..Exception at memory location)

Comment: Does `M` have any data at all? None of this works for empty matrices.

Comment: It does. In fact I can presnt it in a window. I am just not able to access it in the usual opencv methods